# Referrer-Policy allowed domains .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, referrer, referrer-policy

Is it possible, instead of "same-origin", to specify a list of domains that are allowed to receive a referrer?

Answer (score 1):

The [Referrer-Policy](https://www.w3.org/TR/referrer-policy/) specification makes no mention of being able to specify specific domains that would receive a `Referrer`.